# Generic class with expressions throws error in Linq-To-Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

I have some entity `Logging` which implements `ILogging`, let's say it has only two properties:

```
public partial class Logging : ILogging
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
public interface ILogging { int ID {get; set;} }
```

I originally had a static class `Logging.Q` which contains static `Expression<Func<Logging,bool>>` fields, but now I want to be able to write the expressions for `ILogging` if they only need `ID`:

```
public partial class Logging
{
    public static Q<T> where T : ILogging
    {
        public static Expression<Func<T,bool>> IDOne = l => l.ID == 1;
    }
}
```

When I call the expression like this:

```
var log = ctx.Logging.Where(Logging.Q<Logging>.IDOne).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the notorious "linq to entities only supports...":

> Unable to cast the type 'Entities.Logging' to type 'Entities.ILogging'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

But I don't know why. I define my generic type on the class `Q` so runtime it should be known I'm dealing with `Logging` and not `ILogging`. Is there any way around this?

Comment: how come the initial definition of Logging  class is not marked with the keyword partial or is it just ommitted here

Comment: I dont know if this will solve your problem, but at one point in time, I remember having to add class to the constraint. So I had  where T class, ILogging

Comment: That solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a C# compiler bug or defect in expression trees.

When the constraint is `where T : ILogging` or `where T : struct, ILogging`, the generated expression is `{l => (Convert(l).ID == 1)}`, i.e. includes a cast (note the `Convert`) which in turn causes the notorious EF exception.

However, putting a `class` constraint removes the cast and EF is just happy:

`where T : class, ILogging` results in `{l => (l.ID == 1)}`

Comment: The class constraint did it